# How can I change a variable base on the value from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script

How can I change the variable, in my case "docFileID" based on the user selection from the HTML.
For example, if the user select month-8 then the docFileID will equal = " qwer"
or if the user select month-9 the docFileID = "jklk" and so on.

I have tried this but it is not working. I get this error in the console:
**Uncaught  at createPdf (Code:30)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-field " style="padding:0.2cm;" >
                <select name="name" class="browser-default" id="sel">
           <option value="" disabled selected> Choose your option</option>
                  <option value="1">month-8</option>
                  <option value="2">month-9</option>
                  <option value="3">month-10</option>
                  <option value="4">month-11</option>
                  <option value="5">month-12</option>
                </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function addRecord (){
   
 var id =   document.getElementById('id').value;  
 var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
 var dep =  document.getElementById('dep').value;
 var job =  document.getElementById('job').value;

 var sel;    
    if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "mothe-8"){
        sel = '1zjkJ8f';
    }
    else{
      if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "month-9"){
          sel = '1mWjyTVx';
      } else{
          sel = '' ;
      }
      if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "month-10"){
        sel = '1s1GnG3fB7';
    } else{
        sel = '' ;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "month-11"){
        sel = '1OKuviyHRiWW';
    } else{
        sel ='' ;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("sel").value == "month-12"){
        sel = '1WbzrU12VEwuMsoE';
    } else{
        sel = '' ;
    }
    }
    
      
 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).createPdf(name,id,dep,job,sel);
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).createPdf();
   
   } // addRecord  ended
```

code that I want to change is its id :

```
function createPdf (name,id,dep,job,sel,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {


    var docFileID= sel;
    
  
} // createPdf closed
```

Comment: your if is checking against the text of the option instead of the value (eg the value of month-8 is 1).  You also have a typo in your first if

Comment: If you look at your options, the values are 1, 2 3, etc not month-8, month-9, etc.  Your if is checking for month instead of 1 so you will always end in the else.  Your typo is "mothe-8"

Comment: thank you I know my mistake in the text, not the option value. once I changed it it worked.

Answer (score 0):

the `value` property refers to the value in the HTML, not to the text of the `option` element. Also, the logic is a mess, you should use a `switch` or at least `else if`

```js
function addRecord(){
   var sel;  
   switch(document.getElementById("sel").value){
    case "month-8":
      sel = '1zjkJ8f';
      break;
    case "month-9":
       sel = '1mWjyTVx';
       break;
    case "month-10":
        sel = '1s1GnG3fB7';
        break;
    case "month-11":
        sel = '1OKuviyHRiWW';
        break;
    case "month-12":
        sel = '1WbzrU12VEwuMsoE';
        break;
   default:  
        sel = '' ;
    }
    console.log(sel);
 }
```

```html
<div class="input-field " style="padding:0.2cm;" >
                <select name="name" class="browser-default" id="sel" onchange="addRecord()">
           <option value="" disabled selected> Choose your option</option>
                  <option value="month-8">month-8</option>
                  <option value="month-9">month-9</option>
                  <option value="month-10">month-10</option>
                  <option value="month-11">month-11</option>
                  <option value="month-12">month-12</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the js to

```
var sel;    
    if(document.getElementById("sel").value == 1){
        sel = '1zjkJ8f';
    }
    else {
      if(document.getElementById("sel").value == 2){
          sel = '1mWjyTV';
      } else if (document.getElementById("sel").value == 3){
          sel = 'RLbSNM';
      } else if(document.getElementById("sel").value == 4){
         sel = '1OKIZ_xvtfNGNeUU3VNME';
    } else if (document.getElementById("sel").value == 5){
        sel = '1OKuv0-jIZ_xvtfNGNeUU3VNME' ;
    }    
    }
```